# How to use FastCGI with C++ on IIS 7.5

Tags: visual-c++, iis, fastcgi

Has anyone figured out how to run a C++ app with FastCGI under IIS 7.5?

Answer (score 0):

IIS only implements the FastCGI required API for the server, and it is your responsibility to implement the rest in your own C++ app, so that it works with not only IIS but any other FastCGI enabled web server.

http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh831548.aspx

You can see from the above link that IIS accepts any executable that meets the basic requirements.

You might refer to PHP or Python's IIS integration so as to learn about the technical details,

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/iiswsgi/0.3

They are open source, so you might find something useful from the code base.

Comment: Much of what I read seems to indicate that PHP is the most common used language for MS/IIS/FastCGI (Much more documentation, samples, etc). Wonder if it would be easier to just use PHP and then have PHP call my code put into a DLL?

Comment: If your app is suitable to be called by another app (ASP.NET or PHP), yes you can use that approach. Microsoft officially supports PHP via FastCGI on IIS (6 and above), so if you don't plan to write the FastCGI client in C++, you can wrap your app up via PHP.